# Entity Framework : Entity from a View

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, entity

in my database a have an invoice table and a payment table.
i have a transactions view that shows payments and invoices.
i created an entity from that transaction view.

in my application i want to be able to add a payment from the transaction screen (which is a datagrid of transaction entities) and that the list of transactions be updated.

right now I can achieve this by saving the changes and refreshing the entity list.

Is there a way to do this without saving changes to the db ? like temporarily adding the payment to the transaction view ?